# Yii comparing attribute values of two different models

Tags: php, yii

In my web application I need to compare the attribute values of two different models

I want to compare the value of  attribute named  `booked_quantity` of a model named `BookVegetable`  to  the value of a  attribute named `offered_qty` of  a model name `ProducerOffer`. What I want is the values of `booked_quantity`  should be lesser or equal to offered_qty but not greater. I tried searching it  but no where I found for comparing two different model attribute values.
 How should I proceed ? or should I compare it in the controller itself? and generate flash error message?
The code I tried but in vain

```
public function compareBookedQuantity($booked_quantity,$params){
    $count = BookVegetable::model()->findByAttributes(array('booked_quantity'=>$booked_quantity));
    if ($count > $this->offered_qty){
        $this->addError($booked_quantity,'Please enter a quantity lesser than offered quantity');
    }
}

public function rules()
    {

        return array(

array('offered_qty','compareBookedQuantity'),
);
}
```

In my form I have values of both models. How should I compare the attribute values ? please help
The relations function in ProducerOffer model.

```
public function relations()
    {
        return array( 'producerOfferBookVegetableRelation'=>array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'BookVegetable','id'),  

        );
    }
```

Comment: we don't see relation between this models

Comment: Ya I will paste that function. I have pasted that code for the relation function

Answer (score 0):

First, if you want get booked_quantity, it will looks

```
$count = BookVegetable::model()->findByAttributes(array('booked_quantity'=>$booked_quantity))->booked_quantity;
```

Second,

> public function compareBookedQuantity($booked_quantity,$params)

Here $booked_quantity == 'offered_qty'. It is the name of an attribute.
But i didn't fully understand your question. What model contains compareBookedQuantity function?

Comment: ProducerOffer model contains the compareBookedQUantity function

Comment: Tried that code it says   "Trying to get property of non-object"